# http-request library get JSON from Apache server

Tags: java, php, android, json

I used `kevinsawicki/http-request` [library](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) to send data to Apache server. From this [link](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request#perform-a-post-request-with-form-data), we can send data to server like my code bellow :

```
new Thread(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("data", "A User");

                if (HttpRequest.post(MainActivity.private_ip).form(data).created())
                  Log.i("xxx", "Data sent");
            }
}).start();
```

Web services (*.php)

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["data"]) && $_POST["data"] != '' ){     
        $data = $_POST["data"];

        // some action here

        // response to android client application
        $response[TAG_SUCCESS] = 0;     
        $response[TAG_ERROR_CODE] = 5;
        $response[TAG_MESSAGE] = "Access Denied";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

So, I need to read response in JSON form from server, and unfortunately i don't know. how i do that? What i missed? if I am misunderstanding about the use of this library?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using apache, you might want to look into [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/). It makes sending GET, POST, PUT and other HTTP requests very simple. Here is an example of a GET request sent using this library. [You should be able to get the information you need from this, and manipulate it to fit your needs.](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpGet.java)